# Change of Coordinates Multivariable Calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the region $D$ of the plane in the first quadrant bounded by the hyperbolas $x^2-y^2=1$, $x^2-y^2=4$ and the circles $x^2+y^2=4$ and $x^2+y^2=9$. Use change of coordinates to find the double integral 
$$
\iint_Dx\;dA 
$$
I've graphed the region, but I don't know how to find the bounds.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use Latex to write the Math.

Comment: Hint: $x=\sqrt{\frac{u+v}{2}}$, $y=\sqrt{\frac{v-u}{2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you perform the change of variables
\begin{cases}
x=\sqrt{\frac{v+u}{2}}\\
y=\sqrt{\frac{v-u}{2}}\\
\end{cases}
Your region $D$ becomes much more friendly: it is bounded by $u=1$, $u=4$, $v=4$, $v=9$, i.e. it is a rectangle in the $(u,v)$-plane.

The Jacobian of such a transformation is $\frac{1}{2(u+v)}$.

It follows that
$$
\iint_D x\; dA = \int_1^4\int_4^9\sqrt{\frac{v+u}{2}}\frac{1}{2(u+v)}\;dvdu
$$

I am sure you can take it from there.